# Android Studio's device chooser is shown before Gradle Build completes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, adb

Prior to Android Studio 1.5, the device chooser was shown upon Gradle Build completion.

This allowed to use build time to physically configure devices, make any last minute changes or to ensure that devices were actually connected at the time of install. I also disconnected devices if I wanted to cancel my gradle run without interrumpting my workflow.

With the device chooser showing before Gradle Build completion I am forced to have my devices physically connected **before** starting my build; this makes me lose time I could've saved while performing any connections while the Gradle Build was completing. I am also not ensured that installation won't fail when the build is finished since any of my connected devices could no longer be available by the time the build has completed or adb could even stop responding (which is not that uncommon).

I'm sure it will still a matter of preference for some but, is it possible to configure the device chooser so that it appears **after** Gradle Build has completed and is ready to upload the apk to my devices?

Answer (score 7):

Per the [Android Studio 1.5 Preview 2 release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio15preview2available):

> In 1.5 we've reworked the build+deploy flow such that instead of first building with Gradle and then popping up the "choose a device" dialog, we now immediately ask for a device to push the APK to. Some users were using Run + Cancel to build an APK; **we now added a separate "Build APK" action to the Build menu** for that purpose.

So the only option to start a build without a selected device is to use the Build APK action.

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is for the device chooser to appear after the Gradle Build has completed. Not have it not show at all :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's actually the exact scenario they replaced with this new model.

Comment: How can I add "Build APK" icon next to "Run" icon on the toolbar?

Comment: @hoshi - right click on the Toolbar, select Customize Menus and Toolbars, under Main Toolbar->Toolbar Run Actions, select Add After, then choose Build APK from Main Menu->Build->Build APK

Comment: Wow, that's bad news=( A bit inconvinient workflow=(

Comment: @Bagzerg - it does come with some huge advantages - the debug APKs only need to include a subset of assets (one density of images for instance) and less to push == much faster to install. Not to mention that workflow goes perfectly with 2.0's Instant Run which shaves off even more for debug devices that already have something installed (only installing diffs)

Comment: @ianhanniballake, got it, thanks! Just read about [instant run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) and had a deep insight into your comment! The same way as you showed at [Android Development Patterns S2 Ep 5](https://youtu.be/akP6n9VWHSI?t=51s):D

Comment: @ianhanniballake and many and many disadvantages... Scenario 1: build is so long (3 minutes) I go to make caffe and want take my phone with me, not stay on cable. Scenario 2: I need to run on AVD, but AVD start run with build gradle run and I'm really fast Out of memory... :(