# Choose device after the build in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

Unlike in previous versions, in Android Studio 1.5 the 'Device Chooser' dialog pops up BEFORE the build starts. This is rather annoying as I am used to previous versions, where the dialog pops up AFTER the build finishes.

I usually do some other stuff while the gradle build is running. But this way I click on 'Run', start focusing on something else and later go back to find that the build hasn't even started! This happens to me way too often.

Also the dialog should only appear if the build actually succeeds, there is no point if it fails in my opinion.

Is there a way to reconfigure Android Studio to have the Device Chooser pop up AFTER the build succeeds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810919/android-studios-device-chooser-is-shown-before-gradle-build-completes

Comment: @Rocket thanks, I guess there is no way then. I don't really see why they changed it.